# Which is more beneficial prior to PhD: research experience or a second Masters degree?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I will be applying to do a PhD in Applied Mathematics, and have been advised by some professors to consider doing a second masters degree if I do not get in. I have also approached researchers about collaborating on projects with them to improve my profile, and is currently working on one.

I was wondering: if I fail to get into a PhD program, would it be more beneficial for my next application if I enroll in a second masters degree, or would it be better to continue doing research projects?

**Edit:** Both Suresh and JeffE gave good advice, but I have some points to add.

1. I am already actively doing research with the possibility of publication (will submit but peer review process is iffy).
2. Of course, if I am already doing research with well-known faculty collaborators who will write strong letters of recommendation, there is no need to go for a second masters. But would it be realistic to count on a second masters for the opportunity to work with well-known faculty? (IMHO finding supervisors is quite a crapshoot)

I suppose there are quite a few PhD applicants like me: did a masters, but did not excel. Should they try to get research experience with academic collaborators or go for second masters? (there might not be a right or clear cut answer)

Comment: a second masters degree in a different discipline ?

Comment: @Suresh : Are you asking about my intend? My first masters was in Mathematics and Computer Science. I suppose I would want to do my second masters in an area of applied mathematics (so it will be relevant), but it will unlikely to be also related to Computer Science.

Comment: I don't know of anyone getting two masters degrees in the same field (mathematics).  It makes more sense if the degrees are in different disciplines (say, business or music).

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche : Although it is certainly uncommon, it isn't rare to run into people who did 2 masters in similar but not identical topics (e.g. pure math, then math & comp sci) before starting their PhD in my UK university.

Comment: @Legendre Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’.

Comment: @NobleP.Abraham - I didn't because both of them contain good points that answer my question. How should I pick?

Comment: @Legendre You can choose the one which you find most suitable to your situation. Another way is to choose the one with more votes; but here both answers have equal votes. Then another option is to start a bounty and seek more insightful answers.

Comment: @NobleP.Abraham Neither of them answers my question: both says a second MS allows me to approach researchers to work on projects. But I already doing that. I was asking if I should continue to approach researchers independently to do projects or do an MS to make it "official". Can I edit the question to reflect this?

Comment: Of course, if you feel an edit in the question would attract better answers, try it. Clearly mark the edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is framed oddly.  A master's degree *without* research experience will probably kill your chances for PhD admission, at least into the top programs.

Here's a better framing: **Is a second master's degree the best way to get more research experience?**  Unfortunately, the answer depends on your personal situation.  If you're already doing active research with a strong possibility of formal publication, with well-known faculty collaborators who will write you strong letters of recommendation, then a second MS is probably not necessary.  If that doesn't describe your current research environment, a second MS might be the best way to find such an environment.

Comment: Yes. Although there are some other rewards from doing a masters (grades from coursework, references etc), this is essentially a question about the best way to get more research experience. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 6):

I don't know anything about applied math Ph.D programs. But extrapolating from TCS programs, getting more research experience (and some concrete results) would definitely help. While a second MS doesn't help directly, it helps indirectly because

- you don't have a gap in your resume
- you automatically are placed in an environment where you can approach researchers to work on projects with them.

Comment: I am indeed worried about the gap in my resume caused by my current research activity. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Is it possible to get a second MS in TCS after a first in US universities>

Comment: Why would you want to ?